# Doing Integration Testing, what would be a good way to provide test values from external sources?

Tags: integration-tests

I am building an Integration Testing Solution using Selenium in VS2012, which will be run on a CI server in the near future. I need to provide some way to vary the values being used for testing. The easiest would be to provide the QA testers with a few template spreadsheets, which they can fill in to run tests with those values (for example Log-In, Create new user, Create new Booking, Update Reservation etc).

At this moment I have a Test project using NUnit, and another project that contains the test execution code using Selenium, with sample values hardcoded in workflows for each test.

I have done some searching, but came up with no relevant results. I am either using incorrect terminology, or this has never been done (improbable, I know).

Have you done this, or heard/read about someone who has? I'd like to not reinvent this particular wheel.

Comment: I guess this is what you are looking for: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FitNesse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are describing [Cucumber](http://cukes.info/).

What you're really looking for is Acceptance Test and Behavior Driven Development (ATDD and BDD) tools.  If Cucumber is not what you are looking for, I hope those terms help you in your search.

Comment: Thank you! Cucumber led me to SpecFlow which seems to exactly what I need.